# Issues with Java Spring resttemplate character encoding

Tags: java, json, spring, character-encoding

I'm using the Java Spring Resttemplate for getting a json via a get request. The JSON I'm getting has instead of special character slike ü ö ä or ß some weird stuff. So I guess somethings wrong with the character encoding. I can't find any help on the internet. The code I'm using for now is:

```
        String json = restTemplate.getForObject(
        overPassStatementPostCode,
        String.class,
        params);
```

The overPassStamementPostCode is just a string with placeholders. It gets filled with the parameters in the params Map.

The problem is that the String json doesn't have the wanted encoding.

Thank you for the help.
Best regards Daniel

Comment: Can you log the response headers? Look for character encoding

Comment: the logged header is:    
`{Date=[Mon, 05 Jan 2015 09:23:13 GMT], Server=[Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the encoding in `HttpHeaders`. Below code could help you:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.set("Accept", "text/html;charset=utf-8");

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(
                "http://localhost/hello", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but characters like üäö ß are still not encoded right. The code I'm using now is:     `HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.set("Accept", "text/html;charset=utf-8");

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> json = template.exchange(
                overPassStatementPostCode, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                String.class,params);`

Comment: Could you please try again after changing the charset to `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: changed the charset in the requestHeaders.set method and still no luck.

Comment: logged header is :     `{Date=[Mon, 05 Jan 2015 09:23:13 GMT], Server=[Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Content-Type=[application/json]}`

Comment: In the example code that I gave the content type is `text/html` in your case it should be `application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1`. Could you please confirm if you have made these changes?

Comment: Yeah I made the changes. Sadly there is still not the wanted effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an encoding filter in web.xml?

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
     <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
     <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Never used a web.xml for configuration. Have to read about this. I figure I have to registrate this as an applicationcontext?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a converter that can convert from and to HTTP requests and responses. Here is an example.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to spring-web 5.2 solves the problem. or set writeAcceptCharset property to false belongs to StringHttpMessageConverter and use that convertor further in RestTemplate instance.

```
boolean writeAcceptCharSet = false;
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> c = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
for (HttpMessageConverter<?> mc : c) {
  if (mc instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter mcc = (StringHttpMessageConverter) mc;
    mcc.setWriteAcceptCharset(writeAcceptCharSet);
  }
}
```